# phpDoc в phpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

Почему когда я в phpStorm перед методом или функцией ввожу /** и нажимаю Tab, IDE не вытягивает переменные из метода, а просто печатает комментарии:

```
/**
*
*
?
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что после `/**` надо нажимать Enter.

Comment: сорри, я ошибся в описании, нажимаю не tab, а enter